# Use path regex variable inside Ingress service name match?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to achieve something like the following inside a generic Ingress configuration? Allowing a variable reference in `backend` spec.
I've already found this on https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/7739 but there wasn't any followup on the matter.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: global-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: tool.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /be/(?<Namespace>[^/]+)(.+)?
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: $Namespace.be-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write it in a generic way, but not in the way described in your question.

For this specific use-case, where you would like to insert the "namespace" parameter wherever it is needed, surely Helm is the most suitable tool.

For example:

**values.yaml**

```
namespace: yourNsName
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: global-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: tool.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /be/(?<{{ .Values.namespace }}>[^/]+)(.+)?
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Values.namespace }}.be-service
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

Obviously the entire application will have to be converted to Chart.

Otherwise there is Kustomize and its patches.

Example:

**kustomization.yaml**

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - <PATH WHERE INGRESS FILE IS>

patches:
- target:
    kind: Ingress
    name: global-ingress
  patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /spec/rules/0/http/paths/0/path
      value: /be/(?<NAMESPACE-NAME>[^/]+)(.+)?
    - op: replace
      path: /spec/rules/0/http/paths/0/backend/service/name
      value: NAMESPACE-NAME.be-service
```

It depends on how you structure your repository.

Comment: But this require to re-apply it anytime I need to support a new namespace right?

Comment: It depends on whether we are talking about the installation itself or an overlay. For the installation itself, Helm and Kustomize require "re-apply" of configurations.

Comment: Since i'm handling multi-tenancy with a namespace scope, what I'm trying to do specifically is to set a single ingress which dynamically re-route to the tenant namespace services based on the requested path. Hence the desidered feature would be exploiting the regex group from the path inside the serviceName section.